# GUI - related, how do I(after clicking a control), stop one form and resume code execution after the opened form is closed?

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface

I know the question isn't very clear, I will try to explain, can't provide code because most of the variables are written in my language so you wouldn't be able to understand them.

I'm writing a simple software that maintains a list of cars, their owners and repairs made on the cars(I've developed 3 separate classes for cars, owners, and repairs). Important info is that each car has an attribute which is a list of repairs done to it, and my idea was as follows: I made a form which allows you to enter relevant data about the owner and the car and containing a checkbox saying Has repairs, and a button to add a new object to the list. When I click this button, it checks the status of the checkbox, if it is checked, a new form opens whose constructor receives references to a list and a car containing 2 buttons, 1 to exit the form, the other one to add repairs to the said list. But what happens is, I click the button, and it adds the car while the other form is still in the air, not doing what I need it to do, since the car is already in the list.

To be clear, I need a way to make the code execution stop when I enter this new form, and resume when I leave it. Any help would be welcome!

Comment: How are you showing the new form?

Comment: Without any code it's hard to help you.

Comment: Let its name be form1, in the if that checks the state of the checkbox 
I do form1.Activate(), then form1.Show()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form1.Show()` shows a form and continues execution once the form is opened.

Try `form1.ShowDialog()` - this makes the form modal, meaning it will hold code execution until you close the form.

Comment: Well, it worked, didn't expect it to be this simple, thank you :)